# Is componentWillUnmount good place to automatically save user input when user moves away from the current screen?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

In my react native 0.59 app and react navigation 3.7, the `save` is triggered by clicking the `Save` button to execute the save():

```
  save = async () => {
   ....
  }
```

Then the app will save the user input data into the database. I would like to implement exit-n-save just like those common in mobile app, whenever a user leaves the screen or close the component, then the user input data is automatically saved without explicitly clicking the `Save` button. On that sense, where is the better place to execute the `Save`? Is it in `componentWillUnmount`?

Comment: According to my experience, your methodology may work on Android.
I have ever used this way, but I noticed that it didn't work on iPhone.

Comment: Sounds strange. How to make it work on both android and ios?

Comment: As long as you test it and it works as expected I see no issue with your methodology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`navigation` provides with **`willBlur`** event.
This event will be emitted when user leave current screen.
So you may use this event like this:

```
this.props.navigation.addListener('willBlur',payload=>{
    console.log('will leave current screen');
    // call save function
}
```

Comment: The solution above works with both android and ios?

Comment: Yes, when I used this, I didn't find any issue.

Answer (score 2):

`componentWillUnmount` would be a good place to put that, yes.

Answer (score 2):

I think it depends on the library you're using for navigation, but, generally speaking, I agree with @Jin that using a `willBlur` event, or whatever your library's equivalent is, would be a better place for it.

The reason that I recommend this over `componentWillUnmount` is that some navigation libraries (such as react-navigation) will mount all components at once and keep them mounted until the app is closed, so even though you change screens, the component won't unmount and it wouldn't save your users data. There are options to change this functionality (e.g. setting `lazyLoad = false`), but it would probably be easier and more performant to leave the default settings and just use `willBlur` or the equivalent.